# I signed a second work contracts in Germany, without checking my first contract

Tags: contract-law, employment, germany

I am working in a full-time job and I signed another part-time job for 10 hours per week with a university in Berlin.

After I signed the part-time contract I found in my first contract that I have to inform the company in case of having taking a second job and after I asked them they rejected my request to take on a second job.

What should I do now?

I signed another contract without the permission of my first company.

Comment: This question might get better answers on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just a comment: the first employer actually had no choice with that rejection: labor law allows a maximum of 8 h per working day (there's some room for shifting around time, but an average of > 8h/day is not permitted), so your 2 contracts together would violate labor, and the *employer* (not the employee) is legally responsible.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you start working in your second job, you will be violating your first contract. If you refuse to start working in your second job, you will be violating the second contract. You were very careless.

Not much of a legal question, but the question is how to get out of the mess you created at the lowest possible cost. I would suggest that you go as soon as possible to the second company (the one with the part time contract), tell them that you are very sorry but you didn't read your first contract properly, and that you cannot start working for them. If you seem suitably sorry there's a chance that they will tear up your contract and send you home, with no more damage than a big red "DO NOT HIRE" in you records.

If things don't go nicely (and you don't have any legal right to expect them to be nice about it), you go and get a lawyer.